# Is there a formula for calculating $n^.5$? If so, what is it?

Tags: exponential-sum

I keep getting questions like $4^.6$, and likewise - since nothing online has helped I've reverted to remembering, which is not very good.
So, is there a way to calculate this with a formula?
The only logical way I can think of is: Take $4^.6$, for example. In this equation it would be $4*(4*0.6)$. With my formula, I get $9.6$; but the real answer is $2.29739671$.

Comment: Why do you remember them? Use the calculator.

Comment: Are you asking about calculating square roots or powers of $0.6$? Your post is not clear at all.

Comment: @MathLover how would I put it in the calculator?

Comment: $x=4^.6 \Rightarrow  lnx=.6 \; ln4 \Rightarrow x=e^{.6\;ln4}$. Approximate $e^{.6\;ln4}$ (e.g. with McLaurin series) and here you go! With a scientific  calculator it is $exp(0.6*log(4))$

Comment: Then, the question would be how to approximate $\ln(4)$.  (Of course, there is an effective way to do that, but I think this is not what the OP is aiming for.)

Comment: @BlazeDaBlur Most calculators have a button for $x^y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^{ab}=(x^a)^b$$ holds for every real number $x$. So to calculate $x^{0.6}$ you can use $(x^6)^{1/10}=\sqrt[10]{x^6}$.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{.6∗ln(4)}$

or

$exp(0.6∗log(4))$

Any scientific calculator must have $log$ and $exp$ functions.

See comments above.

Comment: I don't have a scientific calculator.

Comment: @BlazeDaBlur Do you have a phone/computer?